# dplyr: Cross-tabulation with pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

There are two questions about dplyr, which in my case are related by the problem I am trying to solve:

1. How can I cross-classify a `data_frame` using pipes, when trying to pass the resultant of a series of operations to `xtabs`?
2. The argument of a pipe is usually denoted by `.` in `dplyr` & `magrittr`, but this is also the token used to denote *everything else* in the formula interface. I know that there is an open issue on `dplyr` somewhere (can't locate it right now) which talks about replacing `.` with `_`.

Here is an example:

```
wakefield::r_data_frame(
  n = 100,
  cat1 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  cat2 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  cat3 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  bin1 = r_sample_logical()
) %>%
  dplyr::filter(bin1) %>%
  xtabs(. ~ cat1 + cat2 + cat3, data = .)
```

which fails with the output:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = . ~ cat1 + cat2 + cat3, data = .) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable '.'
```

because `magrittr` is replacing the first `.` with the resultant `data_frame` of the previous computations. One way is to omit the first period altogether, like so:

```
wakefield::r_data_frame(
  n = 100,
  cat1 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  cat2 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  cat3 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  bin1 = r_sample_logical()
) %>%
  dplyr::filter(bin1) %>%
  xtabs( ~ cat1 + cat2 + cat3, data = .)
```

But what if the `.` needed to go on the other side of the `formula`?

## Edit:

As pointed out by @MrFlick, `xtabs` does not take a RHS `.` anyway. I thought that this problem could just as well be exemplified using the RHS `.` conflict which I expected using the code:

```
wakefield::r_data_frame(
  n = 100,
  cat1 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  cat2 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  cat3 = r_sample_factor(x = LETTERS[1:3]),
  bin1 = r_sample_logical()
) %>%
  dplyr::filter(bin1) %>%
  dplyr::select(-bin1) %>%
  xtabs( ~ ., data = .)
```

but this does work exactly as expected. Can someone explain why `magrittr` is not trying replace the first `.` with the `data_frame`?

Comment: use a string formula and paste in `paste(names(.), collapse = '+')` as necessary

Comment: Where does `wakefield::r_data_frame` come from? I'm having difficulty reproducing the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick The namespace lookup indicates where it comes from, in this case [here](https://github.com/trinker/wakefield).

Comment: I googled it and that was not near the top of the pile. Packages not on CRAN are not easy to find if you don't know where to look. You should make sure to include that in the question itself. Also, your problem/issue doesn't seem contingent on that package so why require it as a dependency for your minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Also, in what cases is a `.` valid on the left-hand side of a formula? Are you claiming it works when not using magrittr?

Comment: @MrFlick Because, as I well know, that without an MWE, there would be further trouble. And the `wakefield` package is an easy way to generate data for examples.

Comment: @MrFlick Great catch. I will reword my question to ask about `.` on the RHS.

Comment: Why not use count()?

Comment: @hadley Need the table layout for easy reading. Your suggestion is good too, which would be to `group_by` and `count`.

Comment: @hadley Or, as I have just realised, `count` does the `group_by` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`magrittr` does not replace periods (".") in formulas. That behavior is described briefly in the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) (search for "formula").

Comment: I googled to see if `magrittr` was intelligent about that sort of thing -- thanks for the reference.